# type mismatch exception :cannot convert String (java.String) to required type (java.lang.Integer)

Tags: java, spring-boot, sqlite

I have been trying to make a form submission in my application but i keep getting the following error
`2021-07-05 21:40:38.910[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m18360[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36m.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Resolved [org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.issuetracking.app.enitities.Equipment'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer] for value 'lights'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "lights"]`

And i have written my controller like so. it consists of the handler method that display the list of data entered using the form . the handler method that adds the equipment details in the form. However, i have been trying to do this on the same page so that when i submit data in the form it should be displayed in a table below the form on the same page. Where i have gone wrong and how can i achieve this? Thanks in advance.

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import com.issuetracking.app.enitities.Equipment;
import com.issuetracking.app.services.EquipmentService;

@Controller
public class EquipmentController {

    private EquipmentService equipmentService;

    public EquipmentController(EquipmentService equipmentService) {
        super();
        this.equipmentService = equipmentService;
    } 
    
    @GetMapping("/equipment")
    public String listEquipment(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("equipment",equipmentService.getAllEquipment()); 
        return "equipment";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/equipment/new")
    public String addEquipment(Model model) {
         Equipment equipment = new Equipment();
        model.addAttribute("equipment", equipment); 
        return "equipment"; 
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/equipment")
    public String saveEquipment(@ModelAttribute("equipment") Equipment equipments) {
    System.out.println(equipmentService.saveEquipment(equipments));
    return "redirect:/equipment";
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Could you show as the input that causes this log

Comment: @MaroineMlis Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer] for value 'lights'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "lights"] `<form  action="#" th:action="@{/equipment}" th:object = "${equipments}" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="equip">Name of Equipment</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="equip" th:field="*{equipment}" placeholder="Enter Equipment here...">
  </div>`

Comment: i mean the Equipment class

Comment: @MaroineMlis `
 @Column(name="Name_of_equipment")
 private String equipment; `

Comment: this class import com.issuetracking.app.enitities.Equipment ?

Comment: @MaroineMlis No it isnt that is the package name `package com.issuetracking.app.enitities;`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error i would say there is a attributed 'filled' with the String value "lights". And these value can't be converted into an Integer during mapping because for the corresponding attribute there is an Integer expected. I would say, the input object is not correct.

Comment: but in the entity class the type specified for equipment attribute is String and the only integer present is the no attribute.